# How to create a new line?

Tags: shell, hp-ux

In the below command I am sending the mail . in the mail the meter id is being sent

```
if [ -s "$TMP_RPT_FILE" || -s "$TMP_RPT_FILE1" ]
then

        if  [ -s "$TMP_RPT_FILE" ] 
        then
        print "Meters with READINGS ONLY for $RPT_DT" > $RPT_FILE
    cat $TMP_RPT_FILE | uniq >> $RPT_FILE
        fi

        if [ -s "$TMP_RPT_FILE1" ]
        then
        print "Meters with id for $RPT_DT" > $RPT_FILE
        cat $TMP_RPT_FILE1 | uniq >> $RPT_FILE
        fi
    cat $RPT_FILE | \
    $MAILCMD -s "$HOST: Meters with READINGS Only and No Profile Data for $RPT_DT" $MAILLIST
fi
```

For Meter with id
the mail is coming like this

```
output-Meter with Id for 27 Jul PPPP1222344556
```

I want the output to be printed like this:

```
Meter with Id for 27 Jul
PPPP1222344556
```

What should I do?

Comment: Meter with Id for 27 Jul                                                                                                  PPPPPPPP12344556

Comment: I want a space between Jul and PPPPPPPP12344556 so that this PPPPPPPP12344556 will come down

Comment: What is the value of `RPT_DT` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ksh93 (not `ksh` or `sh`), then you can use `$'\n'` to represent a newline character.

```
${RPT_DT%${RPT_DT#* * }}$'\n'${RPT_DT#* * }
```

Comment: you mean to say i should use the bash expression like this  print "Meters with id for ${RPT_DT%${RPT_DT#* * }}$'\n'${RPT_DT#* * }" > $RPT_FILE ??

Comment: its now coming like this Meters with No Profile data for $'
'27-Jul-153412014917AAAAAAAA

Comment: @Pooja Please tell, do you see deference between `Meter with Id for 27 Jul PPPP1222344556` and `Meters with No Profile data for $' '27-Jul-153412014917AAAAAAAA` which you have posted above?

Comment: @Costas Evidently the script isn't being executed by a shell that has the `$'…'` syntax.